# Concatenate values from two fields in MSACCESS

Tags: ms-access, concatenation, field, resultset

I need help concatenating two fields and putting the value in the third field.
I do not want to use VBA. Is there a way to do this like in Excel ?

id  title   price   desc

1   Item1    2495   {title + " " +price}

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Description: [title] & " " & [price]
```

Comment: so you have fields named 'Title' and 'Price', correct?  In a query in a blank field you should be able to enter as I have above.

Comment: So I have to make a Query ? I'm not sure how to do that properly I was entering `Description: [title] & " " & [price]` in my desc column in the same row in my table. My fields are called `title` and `price` in lowercase.

Comment: I didn't realize you were trying to do this within a table. See my additional answer.

Comment: Access is not Excel. As well as the above, you could use a form, which is much recommended.

Comment: @RyanL - The first example works now, I have found this [tutorial on Access 2007](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/concatenate2_2007.php) but it's not what I want, I don't want a query with separate table data but to concatenate the data in the fields within the original table. The expression property is only 2010 and up.

Comment: Listen to @RyanL. This is one of the tasks queries are for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add the description in the same table as your title/price, then you can add a calculated field (though not recommended).

Example:
[image]

To do this, you need to create a calculated field, as shown below:
[image]

The properties should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Calculated fields are not usually a good idea. There is no reason to post a new answer, you can expand on your initial answer.

Comment: I tried but I don't see the Calculated Option. [PictureUploaded](http://picpaste.com/data-4sNFibpE.png)

Comment: What version of Access are you running?  The best option would be to create a query to return the description as described in another answer.

Comment: ACCESS 2007, see my comment above.

Comment: Here's a reference to calculated fields in 2007: <http://www.keystonelearning.com/resources/articles/access_2007_creating_a_calculated_field/>